# I want to assign rank following with some condition

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dense-rank, partition-by

I want to assign the rank to 'drug_name' as per the order of 'svcdate' for each 'patient_id' in a dataset. (here, to describe the issue I'm only showing one patient_id in the image)

```
select patient_id
    ,svcdate
    ,drug_name
    ,dense_rank() over(partition by patient_id order by first_date) as rank
from (
    select *
        ,first_value(svcdate) over (
           partition by patient_id, drug_name 
           order by svcdate) as first_date
    from table
)
order by 1,2;
```

With this query I'm getting the following output,

[image]

Although, I want something like this (as shown in image below)

[image]

Please help me understand what I'm missing out in the query and how to address this issue.
Thanks!!

Comment: picture are rather horrible, as the data cannot be cut'n'pasted into the database.

Comment: this data as it stands is unstable, as those last two rows on the 31st august can "change order"

Comment: what database is this question for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using this CTE for the data:

```
with data(patient_id, svcdate, drug_name) as (
    select * from values
    (110, '2018-08-09'::date, 'TRANEXAMIC ACID'),
    (110, '2020-05-28'::date, 'TAKHZYRO'),
    (110, '2020-06-10'::date, 'ICATIBANT'),
    (110, '2020-06-24'::date, 'TAKHZYRO'),
    (110, '2020-07-22'::date, 'TAKHZYRO'),
    (110, '2020-07-24'::date, 'ICATIBANT'),
    (110, '2020-08-31'::date, 'ICATIBANT'),
    (110, '2020-08-31'::date, 'TAKHZYRO')
)
```

And using [CONDITONAL_CHANGE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_change_event.html) gives you what you want

```
select patient_id
    ,svcdate
    ,drug_name
    ,CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT( drug_name ) OVER ( 
        PARTITION BY patient_id ORDER BY svcdate )+1 as rank
from data
order by 1,2;
```

gives:

| PATIENT_ID | SVCDATE | DRUG_NAME | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 110 | 2018-08-09 | TRANEXAMIC ACID | 1 |
| 110 | 2020-05-28 | TAKHZYRO | 2 |
| 110 | 2020-06-10 | ICATIBANT | 3 |
| 110 | 2020-06-24 | TAKHZYRO | 4 |
| 110 | 2020-07-22 | TAKHZYRO | 4 |
| 110 | 2020-07-24 | ICATIBANT | 5 |
| 110 | 2020-08-31 | ICATIBANT | 5 |
| 110 | 2020-08-31 | TAKHZYRO | 6 |

Answer (score 1):

We can try to use `LAG` window function in the subquery to get each previous drug_name, then compare by condition aggregate window function to make `rank` column.

```
select patient_id
    ,svcdate
    ,drug_name
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN prev_drug_name <> drug_name THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) over(partition by patient_id order by first_date) as rank
from (
    select *,LAG(drug_name) OVER(partition by patient_id ORDER BY svcdate) prev_drug_name
    from table
)
order by 1,2;
```